# How to create a dynamic form in android containing a layout

Tags: android, dynamic

I want to create a dynamic form , which would create another layout when an add button is clicked and to get data from the edittexts of that form

Comment: [Take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

Try this way..

```
public class DynimicForm extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initView();
}

private void initView() {
    LinearLayout relativeLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    // Defining the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
    // In this case I want to fill its parent
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    relativeLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    // Creating a new TextView
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Test");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams et = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setHint("Enter name");
    editText.setLayoutParams(et);
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText("Click me");
    button.setLayoutParams(et);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), editText.getText().toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tv.setText(editText.getText().toString().trim());
        }
    });
    // Defining the layout parameters of the TextView
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    // Setting the parameters on the TextView
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

    // Adding the TextView to the RelativeLayout as a child
    relativeLayout.addView(tv);
    relativeLayout.addView(editText);
    relativeLayout.addView(button);

    // Setting the RelativeLayout as our content view
    setContentView(relativeLayout, rlp);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply make two activities and follow the process.
You can use Intent and get Intent to get and pass the value to other activity on button click that behaves like what you wanted.